# Custom bower dependency using ng-translate : 404 error when loading JSON resource file

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have created a directive that uses angular-translate and it is working fine with this configuration :

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
  prefix: 'i18n/messages_',
  suffix: '.json'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('fr');
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('fr');
$translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
```

and two files in i18n folders :
* messages_en.json
* messages_fr.json

Now I want this directive to be usable in another angular application so I use it as a bower dependency of my new application with all necessary .js and .html needed but the json files in a single .js file using templateCache.

The directive is working in my new application, however my new application is trying to load the json file from http://localhost:9000/i18n/messages_fr.json ans gives a 404 error.

This error is normal as I do not include the json files in my dependency, however I do not not know where and how I should. If I include them in my bower depdency or add it in templateCache, it is not working.

An easy solution is to copy the file in a i18n/ folder of my application but it is not what I want, I want to reuse the files defined with my directive. I tried modifying the useStatidFilesLoader attributes but without success so far.

**EDIT**

I figured the real problem was I intended to use two configurations of the translateProvider :
 - one with common messages file in my dependency config
 - another one with another message file name in my new application config.
But as it is a provider, hence a singleton, only one configuration gets executed. So it is not possible to load messages from two different files or I missed something in ngtranslate configuration.

What I did is including the common messages file in my bower dependency and add a grunt task in my new application that merge this message file with my new application message file. To do this I use grunt-merge-json.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and here is your answer. All you need is

```
$translateProvider.useLoaderCache('$templateCache');
```

[Would it be possible to support the $templateCache?](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1214)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I can use the template cache but is not solving my problem which results to be linked to the provider singleton fact (see my edit)